# jQuery: change class on click event

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery for a panel to show and hide. There is a small arrow image on it which also changes on hide and show. My code is

```
<div class="trigger-m"><span id="toppanelarrow">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

Now a class is added to_up when the panel opens and to_down when the panel closed. I have respective up and down arrow image for this.

Can someone help me adding a jQuery on click event of 'toppanelarrow' so a new class gets added to the span.

I have tried `$().addClass().removeClass()` but this didn't work.

Update: Please find the fiddle implementation http://jsfiddle.net/B5QUj/4/

Thanks

Comment: show the code and HTML (in http://jsfiddle.net if possible)

Comment: Sorry Guys for replying late. I have coded it in jsfiddle and here is the link.
http://jsfiddle.net/B5QUj/3/

Answer (score 3):

If you have one class on the element to start with:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('to_up to_down');
});​
```

is all you need.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kXNk8/

Comment: this is good fast and way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can try

```
$(this).toggleClass('classname');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try (this adds the class to_down if the span has the class to_up

```
$('#toppanelarrow').click(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('to_up')){
     $(this).addClass('to_down').removeClass('to_up');
   }else{
     $(this).addClass('to_up').removeClass('to_down');
   }
});
```

this could also be written

```
$('#toppanelarrow').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('to_up to_down').;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#yourClassID").addClass("cssClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the wanted effect:

Html:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click it" />

<div class="box">
    <span>Tekst</span>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $(".box").toggle();
    });    
});
```