# Toggle text glow in navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, navbar, glow

Hello all, newbie here.  I have tried my best to find a simple solution through searching, but I have not come across anything that works for me.  My site uses a navbar that hides/shows divs to "change the page" (all contained in one HTML file) and currently there is no visual indicator of which of these items is the current page.  How can I make it so that when a menu item is clicked, a text glow effect is enabled on that item (a CSS3 effect, I would assume) and the text glow on all other menu items is toggled off?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's a lot to answer, do you have any examples or links? If no, you may want to try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/YxRqp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/usd6v5kp/1/

HTML:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="Test1" onclick="glow1()">ITEM ONE</p>
    <p id="Test2" onclick="glow2()">ITEM TWO</p>
    <p id="Test3" onclick="glow3()">ITEM THREE</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery:

```
function glow1() {

        $('#Test1').addClass('class1');
        $('#Test2').removeClass('class1');
        $('#Test3').removeClass('class1');
        }



    function glow2() {


        $('#Test2').addClass('class1');
        $('#Test1').removeClass('class1');
        $('#Test3').removeClass('class1');
        }

    function glow3() {

        $('#Test3').addClass('class1');
        $('#Test1').removeClass('class1');
        $('#Test2').removeClass('class1');
        }
```

CSS:

```
 .class1 {
    text-shadow: 0 0 12px #ff0000
}
```

Comment: Hey, I know this question is a year old but I realized I forgot to mark this answer as correct, as I did end up using this.  I actually simplified it even further, by giving each list item the same class, so when the function is called it technically removes the "active" class from each item and then applies it to item clicked.

     `function glow1() {

             $('.list-item').removeClass('activeClass');

             $('#list-item-1').addClass('activeClass');

             }`

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript for that. You can have 2 css classes. When menu item clicked the class name changes. This use Jquery to make it easy. Good luck. [See more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703475/jquery-change-class-on-click-event)